# Imagemagick: TIF converted to JPG looks terrible

Tags: php, imagemagick

Im trying to convert a bunch of `tif` files to `jpg` I've tried ImageMagick's `-quality`, `-density` settings, and still the created file image quality looks terrible.

```
  exec('/usr/bin/convert /mypath/myfile.tif -trim -quality 100 /mypath/converted.jpg');
```

Is there something I can add to this command to make the jpg look a lot better? Im certain the source file looks good.

Before conversion (.tif):
[image: Before]
After conversion (.jpg):
[image: After]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your TIFF is binary and needs to be converted to 8-bit grayscale. So change your ImageMagick command to

```
exec('/usr/bin/convert /mypath/myfile.tif -type grayscale -trim -quality 100 /mypath/converted.jpg');
```

If that does not work, then post a link to your actual tiff file and not one that has been converted to jpg

Comment: Thanks! Would binary ever be a color image?

Comment: Binary is always just black and white (1-bit). But you could change the type to truecolor, then it would be 24-bit image with all three channels the same grayscale image. So you could use -type truecolor rather than -type grayscale

Comment: If you want a two-color image (not black/white or even black/white), then GIF would be the way to go rather than JPG. JPG does not do well with large regions of solid color due to its compression.

Comment: Your problem may simply be due to jpg compression. You could try a GIF output as mentioned above, if you file is truly binary.

Comment: I swear it was working yesterday after changing it. However its back to being terrible quality. The code Im using, as well as the source tif, and generated jpg are located here: http://auditordata.com/imagetest.php if you feel like taking a look.

Comment: Your tiff file seems to be corrupt when I download it and try to view it. ImageMagick says it is a PDF and not TIFF. Perhaps a Tiff imbedded in a PDF. One of my viewers also says it is a PDF

Comment: Hmm. I have two source files I can use... a *.tif & *.tif.pdf Both look fine at the source and when viewed or converted to jpg from an online converter.

Comment: *.tif.pdf is probably a tif imbedded in a vector PDF shell. Do both convert properly or not? Does the .tiff work? Does the .tiff.pdf work? I suspect the .tiff will work OK. The .tiff.pdf will need to be enhance with a larger density, processed, then resized down or it will look bad.  You probably processed the .tiff yesterday and it worked fine. But today, you probably used the .tiff.pdf and that may not work unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

For your .tiff.pdf files, try this in ImageMagick

```
convert -density 288 C0000005.tiff.pdf -alpha off -trim +repage -type grayscale -resize 25% -quality 92 C0000005.jpg
```

This is what I get:

[image]

If you want a better quality result, you can try -quality 100, but I doubt it will make the quality much better and will increase the file size. Better would be to increase the -resize 25% to some larger value such as 33% or 50%. That will make the resulting jpg dimensions larger.  This process is called supersampling, namely, making the PDF bigger and then resizing afterwards.